# Locking needed for this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking, sql-server-2012

This is my scalar function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetInstrumentID]
(
    @ParentDocumentID   int
)
RETURNS varchar(14)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @InstrumentID   varchar(14) = ''
    Declare @FilingNumber   int = 0
    Select @InstrumentID = InstrumentID
        From Documents
            Where DocumentID = @ParentDocumentID

    Select Top 1 @FilingNumber = FilingNumber
        From Documents Where ParentDocumentID = @ParentDocumentID
            Order By FilingNumber desc

    Set @InstrumentID = Left(@InstrumentID,9) + Right(
        '000' + Cast((IsNull(@FilingNumber,1) + 1) as varchar(3))

    , 3) + '00'

    Return @InstrumentID
END
```

I am worried if 100s of users call this function, would it be possible that many of them receive the same return value? If yes, then how can I ensure that at a time only 1 user gets to execute this function and the rest of them wait?

Comment: use `From Documents WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing in your function that would make it return a different value for two identical concurrent calls. If you need to prevent concurrency, you can use [application locks](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005). This is for SQL Server 2005, there might be something newer in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: How? I am Ordering by FilingNumber and then incrementing that number by 1. If 10 users call, how can we gaurantee that same filing number won't be generated multiple times? If there is nothing that would make it return different value, then I would be the most happy. However, I still feel it can return different values for multiple concurrent calls?

Comment: Also, I think the link you gave would lock whole SQL server. I was thinking may be something like tablock x or something?

Comment: You are not updating `Document.FillingNumber` *in your function* (you probably do it outside). I am no SQL Server expert, but I would expect to see at least an `UPDATE` of this column, a transaction containing the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` and a transaction isolation level set to `SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: Application locks will not lock the whole server, but the lock's scope will be the whole server. This means that any attempt to get the same lock will fail until the lock is released.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPDLOCK hint. UPDLOCK hint tells the SQL Server engine "Don't allow any other read if this row to acquire an UPDATE(lock"U") because I will. UPDLOCK hold lock until the end of the statement or transaction.

Select statement in function body:

```
Select Top 1 @FilingNumber = FilingNumber
From Documents WITH(UPDLOCK)
Where ParentDocumentID = @ParentDocumentID
Order By FilingNumber desc
```